# How to check column value inside case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table structure,

```
ID  TypeID  No
1   10  50
2   20  100
```

I need to get the `No` column value by checking `TypeID` column value, I did as follows,

```
  select case when ( TypeID = 10) THEN  NO END AS NO1,
  CASE when (TypeID = 20 ) THEN  NO END AS NO2  from SAMPLE_TABLE
```

But its return NULL,

Expected Output is

```
NO1 NO2
1  0
```

Comment: What relationship do the 2 rows have between each other? Why do you end up with 1 row, rather than 2?

Comment: What is the logic to get your expected output?

Comment: @Larnu I need to do it using one, and you mean write two seprate select ?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I'm not clear what u asked :(

Comment: I mean, your input is clear, your expected output is clear, and could you describe how to get the output from that input? For e.g, this query could get your expected output, but we know this is not your expected query: `SELECT 50 AS no1, 100 AS no2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation :

```
with sample_table(ID,TypeID,No) as
(
 select 1,   10,  50   union all
 select 2,   20,  100
)
select max(case when TypeID = 10 THEN  NO END) AS NO1,
       max(case when TypeID = 20 THEN  NO END) AS NO2  
 from sample_table;

NO1  NO2
---  ---
 50  100
```

**Edit**(*depending on your comment*) **:** If `No` column being of `bit` type, then consider :

```
select max(case when TypeID = 10 THEN  NO+0 END) AS NO1,
       max(case when TypeID = 20 THEN  NO+0 END) AS NO2  
 from sample_table;

NO1  NO2
---  ---
1    0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9e431d860dba9bcfafddf470412a4b6a)</kbd>

Comment: I'm really sorry I forgot to say , NO column is bit column

Comment: @thomsan Well, I added an **Edit** to the answer, but sample data in the question for the column `No` doesn't reflect the current case.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach which would be flexible here would be to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TypeID) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN No END) AS NO1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN No END) AS NO2
FROM cte;
```

Comment: I'm really sorry I forgot to say , NO column is bit column

Comment: That doesn't really change any of the answers given, but in any case how can 50 and 100 fit into a bit column?